# SQL - group by part of a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a column which has values like
       `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.6; en-us; SGH-T989 Build/GINGERBREAD)`  and `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us)` and some other variations

how do I make a group by clause by just taking into account the first few characters say `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android` and `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone`

can someone please suggest

Comment: `regexp_substr` is your friend here.

Comment: What is the algorithm for figuring out which characters you want to group by?  How do you know, for example, to stop at `Android` and not group on the `2.3.6`?  Or to stop at `CPU iPhone` and not group by the `OS 4_3_2`?

Comment: @Justin Cave   i was thinking maybe I can count number of characters and usually after certain number characters i'll hit either 'android' or 'iphone' and that should be sufficient.

Comment: @user1207289 - So, do you just want the part of the string up to and including the first occurrence of either the word `iPhone` or `Android`?

Comment: @Justin Cave   yes, that is even better than counting characters, if we can do that.

Comment: @Colin 't Hart @Justin Cave   looks like this works `regexp_substr(CE.USER_AGENT,'(Android)|(iPhone)',1,1,'i')` .just in case someone else is looking for something like this. thanks all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use metacharacters like *. They work in the sameway as metacharacters in shell script. You can get more information here.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm

Also

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#SQLRF00501

Answer (score 0):

You can create new temporary table with the same columns as your table and just insert the characters (substring) that you want from that string, then do the group by in the temp table you created (dont forget to drop the temp table in the end):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
....more variables, same as in original table  
somevar varchar
)

insert into #temp
select substr(originaltable.somevar,0,5) from originaltable

select somevar from #temp
group by somevar

drop table #temp
```